# Using a JMS QueueConnectionFactory in web application

Tags: jms, websphere

I have defined QueueConnectionFacotry name jms/testapp/testappQCF on Websphere. Now If I want to use this in my web application, can I use it directly liek below

```
@Resource( name="jms/testapp/testappQCF")
private QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

Or do I need make an entry in web.xml like below

```
    <resource-ref>
     <res-ref-name>jms/testapp/testappQCF</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
    </resource-ref>
```

Comment: `@Resource` should work. Are you having any problems?

Comment: I have onMessage method in my class which is listening a message.But it is not being invoked at all.

Comment: You need to provide more information. If you are using MDB, then it should be bound to the active specification. Also make sure you are pointing to the right queue and the queue is not empty.